# Javascript pass changing object

Tags: javascript, object, pass-by-reference

I don't know if it's even possible but we made a statemachine in Javascript.

We have the variable

currentState = stateA

I'd like to pass the currentState as a parameter into an other object, that calls it's methods.

The state changes, so we have

currentState = stateB

The object that uses the currentState call's the stateA method, not the stateB

Is it possible to let it change with it? (pass by reference???)

Comment: Can you post the logic or code you are using, it appear that you are changing the state after the object using the currentState value.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it if you wrap it in another object. Just as a very rough draft to get you started, you can try this sample:

```
var StateManager = { currentState: 'stateA' };

function doStuff(sm) {
  console.log(sm.currentState); // stateA
  changeState(sm);
  console.log(sm.currentState); // stateB
}

function changeState(sm) {
  sm.currentState = 'stateB';
}

doStuff(StateManager);
```

Just for the sake of it, here is an idea of what happens:

```
var o = {a:1}; // o points to an object
f(o); // the pointer is passed to the function

function f(obj) { // obj points to the object above
   obj.a = 2; // actual object changed
   obj = null; // obj no longer points to that object, but the object remains
}
console.log(o); // o still points to the object
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. But you can get around it easily. For example:

```
var StateMachine = (function() {
  var _state= null;
  return {
    setState: function(state) {
      _state = state;
    },
    getState: function() {
      return _state;
    }
  }
})();

var stateA = {
  hello: function() {
    alert("state A");
  }
};

var stateB = {
  hello: function() {
    alert("state B");
  }
}

setState(stateA);
getState().hello(); // prints "state A";
setState(stateB);
getState().hello(); // prints "state B";
```

This way you make sure the state is only changed via the getter/setter functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's possible in some extent.
It all depends on browser support of Ecma script 5.

Have a look at the `Object.defineProperty` in [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). There you can define `get` and `set` methods for your property.

For a more compatible way of doing this use a closure where you define a private variable that you later access with your own defined `getState` and `setState` methods.